# Tkinter...space invaders...enemy movement

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing simple space invaders clone using Tkinter. Currently I am trying to figure out a way how to move enemies down in a single line at some speed...when I set the speed in `move_enemy()` to 1000ms the game starts to lag out. Help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
# creates window
window = Tk()
size = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.title("This is a window")
# set up geometry using string formatting operator %
window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1000, 1000, 10, 10))
window.update()
# creates canvas
global canvas
canvas = Canvas(window, bg='green')
# pack is a layout manager
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.update()
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 1000, 1000, 0, fill="orange", width=10, outline="white",     tag="border")

def shooting():
    global loaded_gun

    c = canvas.coords("player")
    canvas.create_line(c[0],c[1] + 20,c[2],c[3],width=5,fill="yellow",tag="shot")
    loaded_gun = 0


def move_shot(name):
    canvas.after(50)
    canvas.move(name,0,-20)
    canvas.update()

def on_key_press(event):

    global canvas,loaded_gun


    c = canvas.coords("player")

    if event.keysym == 'Left' and c[0] > 0:
        canvas.move("player", -20,0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right' and c[2] < 1000:
        canvas.move("player", 20, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'space':
        if loaded_gun == 1:
            shooting()
    elif event.keysym == 'Shift_L':
        loaded_gun = 1
        canvas.delete("shot")

def draw_enemy():
    c = [100,100,170,170]
    inc = 100

    for x in range(0,8):
        for y in range(0,4):
            canvas.create_rectangle(c[0] + inc * x,c[1] + inc * y,c[2] + inc * x,c[3] + inc * y,fill="red",tag="enemy")

def move_enemy():
    canvas.after(1000)
    canvas.move("enemy",0,20)


canvas.create_line(500, 950,500,1000, width=15, fill="red",tag="player")

loaded_gun = 1

draw_enemy()


while True:
    move_shot("shot")
    move_enemy()
    canvas.bind_all('<Key>', on_key_press)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I modified your code - see lines with `# furas` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinterbook: [Widget after method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method)

> You can also omit the callback. If you do, this method simply waits
>   for the given number of milliseconds, without serving any events (same
>   as time.sleep(delay_ms*0.001)).

So `canvas.after(1000)` (without second argument) works as `time.sleep(1)` and it stops all program for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)

---

**EDIT:**

```
from tkinter import *
# creates window
window = Tk()
size = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.title("This is a window")
# set up geometry using string formatting operator %
window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1000, 1000, 10, 10))
window.update()
# creates canvas
global canvas
canvas = Canvas(window, bg='green')
# pack is a layout manager
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.update()
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 1000, 1000, 0, fill="orange", width=10, outline="white",     tag="border")

def shooting():
    global loaded_gun

    c = canvas.coords("player")
    canvas.create_line(c[0],c[1] + 20,c[2],c[3],width=5,fill="yellow",tag="shot")
    loaded_gun = 0
    move_shot("shot") # furas

def move_shot(name):
    canvas.move(name,0,-20)
    canvas.update()
    window.after(50, move_shot, "shot") # furas

def on_key_press(event):

    global canvas, loaded_gun

    c = canvas.coords("player")

    if event.keysym == 'Left' and c[0] > 0:
        canvas.move("player", -20,0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right' and c[2] < 1000:
        canvas.move("player", 20, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'space':
        if loaded_gun == 1:
            shooting()
    elif event.keysym == 'Shift_L':
        loaded_gun = 1
        canvas.delete("shot")

def draw_enemy():
    c = [100,100,170,170]
    inc = 100

    for x in range(0,8):
        for y in range(0,4):
            canvas.create_rectangle(c[0] + inc * x,c[1] + inc * y,c[2] + inc * x,c[3] + inc * y,fill="red",tag="enemy")

def move_enemy():
    canvas.move("enemy",0,20)
    window.after(1000, move_enemy) # furas


canvas.create_line(500, 950,500,1000, width=15, fill="red",tag="player")

loaded_gun = 1

draw_enemy()

window.bind_all('<Key>', on_key_press) # furas

#move_shot() # furas
move_enemy() # furas


window.mainloop()
```